# how to make an animating blob button using js and css?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a button that has the shape of a blob and it has to keep animating

i've tried to make it using a div and the border-raduis but it's not exactly what I wanted to have

```css
body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .blob{
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        background: red;
        background-size: cover;
        animation: animate 3s infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes animate {
        0%, 100% {
            border-radius: 64% 36% 27% 73% / 55% 58% 42% 45%;
        }
    
        25% {
            border-radius: 73% 27% 26% 38% / 73% 36% 64% 27%;
        }
    
        50% {
            border-radius: 28% 72% 44% 56% / 49% 40% 60% 51%;
        }
    
    
        75% {
            border-radius: 40% 60% 70% 30% / 47% 62% 38% 53%;
        }
    
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="blob"></div>
```

here's what I want to acheive:

[image]

I have the svg file and here's the code related to it: but I don't know how to animate it

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="145.674" height="166.22" viewBox="0 0 145.674 166.22">
        <g id="Groupe_14" data-name="Groupe 14" transform="translate(-1700.966 -2837.689)">
          <path id="Tracé_20" data-name="Tracé 20" d="M1977.5,2710.2c-10.74-18.359-2.366-46.848-50.324-38.788s-46.643,29.758-40.99,45.729,18.584,22.436-4.436,43.976-13.428,55.913,28.775,51.076,30.156,19.347,52.486,22.571,29.024-9.6,26.974-25.8-4.111-32.767,11.2-43.692c15.162-10.82,13.807-12.831,12.3-25.244C2007.673,2715.5,1988.238,2728.555,1977.5,2710.2Z" transform="translate(-168.06 168.139)" fill="#fa7268" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1"/>
        </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: you should consider a different approach, that shape is not feasible only playing with border-radius. Try to animate a SVG path instead

Comment: can you attach any tutorial or a link showing how to acheive that? I have the sgv file, cause I'm the one who draw that using adobe xd, but I don't know how to make an animation for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS property clip path with polygon can solve your problem very easily. See the example below.

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
}

.clip-animation { 
  clip-path: polygon(100% 50%,84.70057014808336% 54.5684167277018%,91.0518476172854% 60.99980941685713%,82.33578363789503% 63.39392013277814%,93.30127018922194% 75%,77.76736691019323% 71.30665001530522%,80.05203820042827% 80.05203820042827%,71.30665001530522% 77.76736691019323%,75% 93.30127018922192%,63.39392013277814% 82.33578363789503%,60.99980941685714% 91.0518476172854%,54.56841672770181% 84.70057014808336%,50% 100%,45.4315832722982% 84.70057014808336%,39.000190583142874% 91.0518476172854%,36.606079867221865% 82.33578363789505%,25.00000000000001% 93.30127018922194%,28.693349984694787% 77.76736691019323%,19.947961799571733% 80.05203820042827%,22.23263308980677% 71.30665001530522%,6.698729810778076% 75.00000000000001%,17.664216362104966% 63.39392013277815%,8.948152382714603% 60.99980941685715%,15.299429851916635% 54.568416727701816%,0% 50.00000000000001%,15.299429851916635% 45.431583272298205%,8.94815238271459% 39.00019058314288%,17.66421636210496% 36.60607986722188%,6.698729810778062% 25.000000000000014%,22.23263308980676% 28.693349984694787%,19.947961799571715% 19.947961799571747%,28.69334998469477% 22.232633089806775%,24.99999999999998% 6.698729810778083%,36.60607986722184% 17.664216362104973%,39.00019058314284% 8.948152382714603%,45.43158327229816% 15.299429851916642%,49.99999999999999% 0%,54.568416727701795% 15.299429851916635%,60.99980941685711% 8.94815238271459%,63.39392013277812% 17.66421636210496%,74.99999999999997% 6.6987298107780475%,71.3066500153052% 22.23263308980675%,80.05203820042826% 19.947961799571722%,77.76736691019323% 28.69334998469477%,93.30127018922192% 24.99999999999998%,82.33578363789502% 36.60607986722184%,91.0518476172854% 39.00019058314283%,84.70057014808336% 45.43158327229816%)}

.clip-animation { 
  animation: clip 1s infinite
}

@keyframes clip {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 50%,84.70057014808336% 54.5684167277018%,91.0518476172854% 60.99980941685713%,82.33578363789503% 63.39392013277814%,93.30127018922194% 75%,77.76736691019323% 71.30665001530522%,80.05203820042827% 80.05203820042827%,71.30665001530522% 77.76736691019323%,75% 93.30127018922192%,63.39392013277814% 82.33578363789503%,60.99980941685714% 91.0518476172854%,54.56841672770181% 84.70057014808336%,50% 100%,45.4315832722982% 84.70057014808336%,39.000190583142874% 91.0518476172854%,36.606079867221865% 82.33578363789505%,25.00000000000001% 93.30127018922194%,28.693349984694787% 77.76736691019323%,19.947961799571733% 80.05203820042827%,22.23263308980677% 71.30665001530522%,6.698729810778076% 75.00000000000001%,17.664216362104966% 63.39392013277815%,8.948152382714603% 60.99980941685715%,15.299429851916635% 54.568416727701816%,0% 50.00000000000001%,15.299429851916635% 45.431583272298205%,8.94815238271459% 39.00019058314288%,17.66421636210496% 36.60607986722188%,6.698729810778062% 25.000000000000014%,22.23263308980676% 28.693349984694787%,19.947961799571715% 19.947961799571747%,28.69334998469477% 22.232633089806775%,24.99999999999998% 6.698729810778083%,36.60607986722184% 17.664216362104973%,39.00019058314284% 8.948152382714603%,45.43158327229816% 15.299429851916642%,49.99999999999999% 0%,54.568416727701795% 15.299429851916635%,60.99980941685711% 8.94815238271459%,63.39392013277812% 17.66421636210496%,74.99999999999997% 6.6987298107780475%,71.3066500153052% 22.23263308980675%,80.05203820042826% 19.947961799571722%,77.76736691019323% 28.69334998469477%,93.30127018922192% 24.99999999999998%,82.33578363789502% 36.60607986722184%,91.0518476172854% 39.00019058314283%,84.70057014808336% 45.43158327229816%);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(84.70057014808336% 54.5684167277018%,91.0518476172854% 60.99980941685713%,82.33578363789503% 63.39392013277814%,93.30127018922194% 75%,77.76736691019323% 71.30665001530522%,80.05203820042827% 80.05203820042827%,71.30665001530522% 77.76736691019323%,75% 93.30127018922192%,63.39392013277814% 82.33578363789503%,60.99980941685714% 91.0518476172854%,54.56841672770181% 84.70057014808336%,50% 100%,45.4315832722982% 84.70057014808336%,39.000190583142874% 91.0518476172854%,36.606079867221865% 82.33578363789505%,25.00000000000001% 93.30127018922194%,28.693349984694787% 77.76736691019323%,19.947961799571733% 80.05203820042827%,22.23263308980677% 71.30665001530522%,6.698729810778076% 75.00000000000001%,17.664216362104966% 63.39392013277815%,8.948152382714603% 60.99980941685715%,15.299429851916635% 54.568416727701816%,0% 50.00000000000001%,15.299429851916635% 45.431583272298205%,8.94815238271459% 39.00019058314288%,17.66421636210496% 36.60607986722188%,6.698729810778062% 25.000000000000014%,22.23263308980676% 28.693349984694787%,19.947961799571715% 19.947961799571747%,28.69334998469477% 22.232633089806775%,24.99999999999998% 6.698729810778083%,36.60607986722184% 17.664216362104973%,39.00019058314284% 8.948152382714603%,45.43158327229816% 15.299429851916642%,49.99999999999999% 0%,54.568416727701795% 15.299429851916635%,60.99980941685711% 8.94815238271459%,63.39392013277812% 17.66421636210496%,74.99999999999997% 6.6987298107780475%,71.3066500153052% 22.23263308980675%,80.05203820042826% 19.947961799571722%,77.76736691019323% 28.69334998469477%,93.30127018922192% 24.99999999999998%,82.33578363789502% 36.60607986722184%,91.0518476172854% 39.00019058314283%,84.70057014808336% 45.43158327229816%,100% 50%);
  }
   100% {
    clip-path: polygon(91.0518476172854% 60.99980941685713%,82.33578363789503% 63.39392013277814%,93.30127018922194% 75%,77.76736691019323% 71.30665001530522%,80.05203820042827% 80.05203820042827%,71.30665001530522% 77.76736691019323%,75% 93.30127018922192%,63.39392013277814% 82.33578363789503%,60.99980941685714% 91.0518476172854%,54.56841672770181% 84.70057014808336%,50% 100%,45.4315832722982% 84.70057014808336%,39.000190583142874% 91.0518476172854%,36.606079867221865% 82.33578363789505%,25.00000000000001% 93.30127018922194%,28.693349984694787% 77.76736691019323%,19.947961799571733% 80.05203820042827%,22.23263308980677% 71.30665001530522%,6.698729810778076% 75.00000000000001%,17.664216362104966% 63.39392013277815%,8.948152382714603% 60.99980941685715%,15.299429851916635% 54.568416727701816%,0% 50.00000000000001%,15.299429851916635% 45.431583272298205%,8.94815238271459% 39.00019058314288%,17.66421636210496% 36.60607986722188%,6.698729810778062% 25.000000000000014%,22.23263308980676% 28.693349984694787%,19.947961799571715% 19.947961799571747%,28.69334998469477% 22.232633089806775%,24.99999999999998% 6.698729810778083%,36.60607986722184% 17.664216362104973%,39.00019058314284% 8.948152382714603%,45.43158327229816% 15.299429851916642%,49.99999999999999% 0%,54.568416727701795% 15.299429851916635%,60.99980941685711% 8.94815238271459%,63.39392013277812% 17.66421636210496%,74.99999999999997% 6.6987298107780475%,71.3066500153052% 22.23263308980675%,80.05203820042826% 19.947961799571722%,77.76736691019323% 28.69334998469477%,93.30127018922192% 24.99999999999998%,82.33578363789502% 36.60607986722184%,91.0518476172854% 39.00019058314283%,84.70057014808336% 45.43158327229816%,100% 50%,84.70057014808336% 54.5684167277018%);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="clip-animation" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/building-to-be-clipped.jpg">
```